# Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:anyAtmonicType

Tags: xpath, xquery

Hi can someone please help me I am not sure why I am getting

> "Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value
>   has item type xs:anyAtmonicType".

I am trying to group websites by year.

```
 <publications>
    {
    for $x in distinct-values(//www) 
    return 
    <year-Pub>{for $y in //www where $x/year = $y/year
    return <year>{$y/*}</year>}</year-Pub>
    }
    </publications>
```

Comment: Please don't copy code and messages by typing them, use copy&paste instead (there's a typo in the error message). Your question is lacking basic information. Please read the [FAQ] and [ask], and especially [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you want

```
<publications>
    {
    for $x in distinct-values(//www/year) 
    return 
    <year-Pub>{for $y in //www[year = $x]
               return <year>{$y/*}</year>}</year-Pub>
    }
</publications>
```

Alternatively look at "group by" in XQuery 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I am not able to use Xquery 3.0 at this stage

Answer (score 1):

[`distinct-values(...)`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_distinct-values.html) returns a sequence of `xs:anyAtomicType` values, eg. strings or numbers, but never XML nodes (`node()`). When running on a sequence of XML nodes (which `//www` returns), [`fn:data(...)`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_data.html) is implicitly called for each node to convert it to an atomic value.

In the line `for $y in //www where $x/year = $y/year`, you want to perform an axis step starting at `$x`, which subsequently is not possible.

As you didn't give any input or description of what exactly you want to achieve, I cannot help you with a working and tested solution, but as a brief sketch to deal with distinct nodes:

- Fetch the distinct values as before (and make sure they contain what you're aiming at). I guess you need `distinct-values(//www/year` instead).
- Now, loop over all nodes, and during comparison remember the variable is already holding the atomic value, not an element.